# Overwrite multiple partitions using GCSToBigQueryOperator

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow

I am trying to load multiple partitions into a BigQuery partitioned table, however, as per the documentation we can only specify a single partition using '$' in the

```
destination_project_dataset_table
```

property of

```
GCSToBigQueryOperator
```

I don't want to create multiple tasks in airflow and write a sql to handle partition deletion.

Things I have tried:
Passing a list in source_objects mentioning path till each partition,
pass a comma seperated value in

```
destination_project_dataset_table
```

Comment: I don’t understand the problem, a partition is conditioned by the value you want to ingest. If you have a date partition per day and 2 different dates on your rows, BigQuery will ingest these data with 2 partitions.

Comment: I am trying to load multiple partitions say  "20220201", "20220301" into a BigQuery partitioned table which already contains following partition:
    "20220101", "20220201", "20220301"
however, after running the job through Airflow   
GCSToBigQueryOperator.
The BQ table is completely overwritten. Instead of updating just 2 partitions, it overwrites the complete BQ Table and insert 
    "20220201", "20220301" partitions.

Expected output is:
    "20220101", --> as is
    "20220201", --> updated
    "20220301" --> updated

Any guidance on this is appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for these details, can you share with us the code snippet with the usage of `GCSToBigQueryOperator` operator please ?